# How to type the method of a subclass extending an abstract generic class

Tags: angular, typescript

Considering my base class:

```
export abstract class BaseClass<T> {
  BASE_URL = CONFIG.BACKEND_URL
  protected constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
    this.BASE_URL = `${this.BASE_URL}${this.getModelURL()}`
  }
  all<T>(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.http.get<T[]>(this.BASE_URL)
      .pipe(map((response: any) => response.data))
  }
}
```

```
export class TagService extends BaseAPIService<Tag> {
  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {
    super(http)
  }
}
```

When I call my service through
`this.tagService.all().subscribe(tags => this.tags = tags)`

I get `Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'Tag[]'.`

which is solved by typing `this.tagService.all<Tag>().subscribe(tags => this.tags = tags)`

I don't understand why I have to write the type again to `all<Tag>()`, is it the only way to get rid of that error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining `all` with a generic type `T`, you are hiding the generic type `T` of the class.

You wrote the same as:

```js
abstract class BaseClass<T> {
  all<U>(): Observable<U[]> { ... }
}
```

If you want to reuse the type `T` of the class, no need to declare the method as generic, it's the class that is:

```js
abstract class BaseClass<T> {
  all(): Observable<T[]> { ... }
}
```